# Optional time where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have an optional time where clause.

Namely `where('created_at < ?', params[:infinite_scroll_time_buffer])`.

This is included in a series of calls.

I realized that `where` could take a hash, and if the hash is empty, or is missing any attributes, they won't be included. This sounds great, as I could avoid checking if the `params[:infinite_scroll_time_buffer]` is there, and just include the `where` clause and let Rails take care of the rest.

The problem is the following:

```
def action
  options = {}
  options[:created_at] = params[:infinite_scroll_time_buffer]

  Post.method.another_method.where(options).another_method
end
```

That would work, except the SQL Query checks that `post.created_at = ?` instead of `post.created_at < ?` (rightfully so).

I could have a range of times, but I can't for the life of me find a way for Time to reference the beginning of all time, or something like `Time::THE_BEGINNING_OF_EVERYTHING_AS_WE_KNOW_IT_DUN_DUN_DUN`

so that I could then have a range from that to the `params[:infinite_scroll_time_buffer]`. Is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Create a scope inside your *post.rb*:

```
scope :created_before, ->(time) { where('created_at < ?', time) }
```

Now:

```
def action
  options = {}
  Post.method.another_method.where(options).
      created_before(params[:infinite_scroll_time_buffer]).
      another_method
end
```

If you don't have the `params[:infinite_scroll_time_buffer]` present then don't make the query in the first place:

```
def action
  options = {}
  # more operation on options hash here
  posts = Post.method.another_method.where(options)
  posts = posts.created_before(params[:infinite_scroll_time_buffer]) if params[:infinite_scroll_time_buffer].present?
  posts = posts.some_another_method
end
```

Comment: I think you have a syntax error. What did you mean to do with options?

Comment: Corrected. `->(time) { where('created_at < ?', time) }` will create lambda. Also, in action method, I broke the expression into multiple lines for readability. You had `options` in your `action` method so I presumed that you tend to use it for other queries along the way down beneath the example you gave. What am I missing?

Comment: When I use that method and `params[:infinite_scroll_time_buffer]` is nil, I have `created_at < NULL` in the SQL query instead of not happening at all.

Comment: Fixed it by the following: `scope :created_before, ->(time = nil) { where('created_at < ?', time) if time }`

Comment: @David : Why would you pass a parameter if it is not present in the first place? Even if you do, won't your code `options[:created_at] = params[:infinite_scroll_time_buffer]` have the same effect? which will make query: `where created_at IS NULL`.